# CouchDB filtered replication: Amend doc_id after first complete replication

Tags: node.js, couchdb, replication, npm

NPM's (node package manager) registry uses CouchDB to store meta information and tarballs of packages at a CouchDB instance at http://registry.npmjs.org/registry .. I use the following replication document (CouchDB 1.1.0) to replicate a subset of the registry to my corporate CouchDB:

`{
     "_id": "fetch-npm-registry",
     "doc_ids": [
         "coffee-script",
         "nodeunit"
     ],
     "source": "http://couchdb.mycompany.com:5984/registry",
     "target": "registry",
  }`

[BTW, the CouchApp handling this is at https://github.com/isaacs/npmjs.org (also with complete installation instructions)].

If I want to add another dependency to one of my packages, my naive thought was I just amend the `doc_ids` list (say, to `["coffee-script", "nodeunit", "npm"]`) and start the replication again.

This **however doesn't work**: The replication is finished immediately and the package I wanted to add to the replication (in this case `"npm"`) is missing.

[The workaround known to me is to delete the target database, replicate again and - because I also use this local registry to publish my proprietary packages - re-publish my local packages. *sigh*]

---

**Amendment 18.11.2011**

Here's what I think what happens (not at all a CouchDB internals expert, but maybe there is some truth to it):

After the first successful replication, CouchDB stores the last (highest?) *Sequence ID* of the latest document it replicated in a hidden document in the database (I once knew how to access those, pointers welcome). Then, when I change the `doc_ids` this cached information about the last successful replication (the sequence ID) is not invalidated (or cleared). Then, when it's told to replicate again with the same database it compares the *Sequence IDs* and decides everything is fine.

Comment: Have you [checked for conflicts](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html#working)?

Comment: No, but there shouldn't be any. I didn't push (as in `npm publish`) my own version of npm in the meantime. I have some packages that are original content (my proprietary ones) and the rest should be replicated from upstream. These two sets of packages are disjoint.

Comment: Then check for permissions. Error reporting during replication is weak... check the logs too. Some more information would be useful: CouchDB version; compiled or packaged; what OS?

Comment: CouchDB 1.1.0, compiled from source either on OSX (but also happens on Ubuntu). Will make another clean test run with checking logs.

Comment: I wrote what I think happens as an amendment to the original question.

Comment: hmmm... maybe you should report it as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

1)
`http://registry.npmjs.org/registry` is not registry database, but `http://registry.npmjs.org` is.

2)

> { "_id": "fetch-npm-registry", "doc_ids": [ "coffee-script",
>   "nodeunit" ],  "source": "http://couchdb.mycompany.com:5984/registry",
>   "target": "registry", }

Are you sure that you to replicate from `http://couchdb.mycompany.com:5984/registry` and not `http://registry.npmjs.org` ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with Couchbase Single Server 2.0 Developer Preview 5. There it works. My curl command was (but takes quite a few minutes):

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:5984/_replicate' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"doc_ids": [ "coffee-script", "nodeunit", "npm" ], "source": "http://registry.npmjs.org:5984/registry", "target": "registry", "create_target": true}
```

It is based on some Apache COuchDB trunk version.

Could you please try it with Apache CouchDB 1.1.1. I remember that there was a replicator bug with empty IDs (and the npm repository has such a Document), which was fixed.

Cheers,
  Volker